# Помогите найти конвертор DOCX to HTML

Tags: doc, ms-word, php, linux

Всем привет!
Помогите найти найти конвертор, который будет конвертировать DOCX файлы в HTML. Можно под Linux, а можно класс для PHP.
За все варианты буду благодарен.

Comment: Я забыл уточнить, это всё нужно реализовать на PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот, например, [онлайн](http://www.docx2doc.com/convert/docx-to-html.html).

Comment: Я уже разобрался. Вспомнил про Google Docs API